# How to bind configuration value Laravel service provider on run-time?

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, xero-api

I have created custom service provider which extends XeroServiceProvide, Basically, I have multiple Xero Account and I want to change two configuration params value runtime **consumer_key** and **consumer_secret**. Is there a quick way. I have checked [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#contextual-binding) contextual binding but don't know how to use.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use DrawMyAttention\XeroLaravel\Providers\XeroServiceProvider;

class CustomXeroServiceProvider extends XeroServiceProvider
{
    private $config = 'xero/config.php';

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register($configParams = [])
    {
        parent::register();

        if(file_exists(config_path($this->config))) {
            $configPath = config_path($this->config);
            $config = include $configPath;
        }

        $this->app->bind('XeroPrivate', function () use ($config,$configParams) {

            if(is_array($configParams) && count($configParams) > 0){
                if(isset($configParams['consumer_key'])){
                    $config['oauth']['consumer_key']    = $configParams['consumer_key'];
                }

                if(isset($configParams['consumer_secret'])){
                    $config['oauth']['consumer_secret'] = $configParams['consumer_secret'];
                }
            }
            return new \XeroPHP\Application\PrivateApplication($config);
        });

    }
}
```

From Controller I tried changing value like this but bind params not changing dynamically

```
foreach($centers as $center) {

 config(['xero.config.oauth.consumer_key' => $center->consumer_key]);
 config(['xero.config.oauth.consumer_secret' => $center->consumer_secret]);
}
```

**Update 2**

Is there a way I can rebind service container after updating config file values or somehow i can refresh service provider binding?

```
config(['xero.config.oauth.consumer_key' => 'XXXXXXX']);
config(['xero.config.oauth.consumer_secret' => 'XXXXXX']);
// rebind Service provider after update
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? :-)

Comment: yes @Ratto please find the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing. I have created a custom function that sets value on runtime.

```
/**
 * connect to XERO by center
 * @param $center
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function bindXeroPrivateApplication($center){
    $configPath = config_path('xero/config.php');
    $config = include $configPath;
    config(['xero.config.oauth.consumer_key' => $center->consumer_key]);
    config(['xero.config.oauth.consumer_secret' => $center->consumer_secret]);

    
    return \App::bind('XeroPrivate', function () use ($config,$center) {
        $config['oauth']['consumer_key']    = $center->consumer_key;
        $config['oauth']['consumer_secret'] = $center->consumer_secret;

        return new \XeroPHP\Application\PrivateApplication($config);
    });
}
```

I have model called Center.php and I am calling above function from that same model as below.

```
$center = Center::find(1);
self::bindXeroPrivateApplication($center);
```